# Is there a difference between discount and VAT calculations?

Tags: percentages

When I remove VAT I divide by 1.x
e.g. VAT @ 20% 
£1 /1.2 =£0.83

But if want to remove a % discount do I use the same method as above, or the method below?
20% £1 * 20/100 = £0.20
£1 - £0.20 = £0.80

Comment: The second one, for £0.80.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following situation. You have an item that costs 100\$ before VAT. Let's imagine the VAT is 20%. Then the list price will be $100\$\cdot 1.20 = 120\$$. Then that item is put on a 20% sale. The sticker price will then be $120\$ \cdot 0.80 = 96\$$. The difference is that the VAT is **added** while the discount is **subtracted.**

To emphasize, the VAT is added to a base price while discount is substracted from the total price.

Answer (score 0):

So, if the VAT-included price is $\$x$ with a vat of $y\%$ then you can relate $x \rightarrow (100 + y)\%$ and hence get $1 \% \rightarrow \frac{\$x}{(100+y)\%}$ so that your non-VAT-included price is $$\frac{\$x}{(y+100)\%} \times 100$$

For example, in your case where $y = 20$ and $x=\$1$, then the non-vat price is $$\frac{1}{120\%} \times 100 = \frac{1}{1.2} \times 100 \approx \$0.83.$$

Answer (score 0):

You remove VAT from the price *VAT inclusive*. Hence $\times\dfrac1{100 \%+20\%}$.

But you remove the discount from the *undiscounted* price. Hence $\times(100 \%-20\%$).